# Expression for current context/workflowid

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is there any way to write an expression that gets the current context/workflowid? I'd like to do something like

```
Me.WorkflowId.ToString()
```

and pass that as a parameter to an action, but can't find the object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. There are no useful wf instance info items available statically in Expressions.

You can of course create a code activity like:

```
public sealed class GetWorkflowInstanceId : CodeActivity<Guid>{
    protected override Guid Execute(CodeActivityContext context) {
        return context.WorkflowInstanceId;
    }
}
```